# How do I reuse the Ubuntu partition after its uninstallation?

Tags: partitioning

After deleting Ubuntu from partition, I'm unable to make that deleted partition into a new volume.

[image: green coloured partition]

[image: which is unable to turn into a new simple volume]

Comment: I don't use Windows at all these days, but the only thing I can think off is that you already have 4 primary partitions allocated. What I would do is boot into a Gparted Live CD, and create an extended partition. You might have to move the last 2 partitions around a bit in order to get things set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click F: and choose `Extend volume` if you just want the space back. Other than that, try a LIveCD of [gParted](http://gparted.org/download.php). Move the other 2 partitions down and create the new one at the end of the drive.

Windows is quite foolproof with it's partitions but it's suggesting you've got 4 primary partitions so won't allow more; and probably insists on it being *after* all primary partitions, so using gParted will allow you to create a 5th as an extended volume.

If you're using GRUB to dual-boot it should still boot afterwards as partitions should still have the same numbering/UUID.